# Find the pattern - puzzle

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have recently encountered a reasoning question that I have solved half , but I can't solve one part of it. 
Question : 
\begin{align}
     3 + 5 + 6 =&\; 151872  \\[1.3ex]
     5 + 5 + 6 =&\; 253094  \\[1.3ex]
     5 + 6 + 7 =&\; 303585  \\[1.3ex]
     5 + 5 + 3 =&\; 251573  \\[1.3ex]
\end{align}
I could figure out that ,in the first , $1$st $*$ $2$nd ($3 * 5$) equals first two digits of the answer ($15$). This applies for all the other. Similarly , $1$st $*$ $3$rd ($3 * 6$) equals $3$rd and $4$th digit concatenated of the answer ($18$).This also applies in each. 
But I can't figure out how the last two digits are formed in each.

Please tell me how are the last two digits are formed.

Thanks.

Comment: $102+6a-16b+7c$ works fine

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Please explain a bit more. Thank you.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Almost. doesn't work for the first one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $a$ is the first number, $b$ is the second, and $c$ is the third, the required number is obtained by computing $ab + ac -c$ and then reversing the digits.

For example, in the first row:

$3\times 5 + 3 \times 6 - 6 = 27$, and then reverse to get $72$.

Comment: This also seems to be the overwhelming majority opinion if one googles 151872

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
$$
11a - 16b + 7c + 77
$$
Here $a$ is the first number, $b$ the second, $c$ the third. For example
$$
11\cdot 3 -16\cdot5 + 7\cdot 6 + 77 = ...
$$

---

How did I find this? I made the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{5 & 5 & 6 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 \\ 5 & 5 & 3}.
$$
This matrix corresponds to the last three rows above. Then we want to solve
$$
A\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{94 \\ 85 \\ 73}.
$$
And you would get
$$
\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{26.4 \\ -16 \\ 7}
$$
But we have
$$
26.4\cdot 3 - 16\cdot 5 + 7\cdot 6 = 41.2 \neq 72.
$$
This leads to trying to add a constant to all the values of
$$
\pmatrix{94 \\ 85 \\ 73} + \pmatrix{N \\ N \\ N}.
$$
If you make a small program you find out that $N = - 77$ works
$$
\pmatrix{17 \\ 8 \\ -4}.
$$
Then
$$
A^{-1}\pmatrix{17 \\ 8 \\ -4} = \pmatrix{11 \\ -16 \\ 7}.
$$
So, your program should run through values of $N$ and check whether the first row is satisfied. I am not explaining this very well. And this is not a very smart way of doing it. Someone else can probably some up with something more clever.

Comment: Any intuition behind this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be represented as some "positional notation":

$ {\Large 3}\cdot 50611 + {\Large 5} \cdot 49984 + {\Large 6} \cdot 507 - 252923 = {\Large 151872}$,

$ {\Large 5}\cdot 50611 + {\Large 5} \cdot 49984 + {\Large 6} \cdot 507 - 252923 = {\Large 253094}$,

$ {\Large 5}\cdot 50611 + {\Large 6} \cdot 49984 + {\Large 7} \cdot 507 - 252923 = {\Large 303585}$,

$ {\Large 5}\cdot 50611 + {\Large 5} \cdot 49984 + {\Large 3} \cdot 507 - 252923 = {\Large 251573}$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit little more . Thanks.

Comment: @GaurangTandon, it is simply linear combination like 
$\begin{array}{c}
3a+5b+6c+d=151872,\\
5a+5b+6c+d=253094,\\
5a+6b+7c+d=303585,\\
5a+5b+3c+d=251573;\\
\end{array}\tag{1}$
to find $a,b,c,d$, we solve linear system (1).

Comment: @GaurangTandon, but your observation that 3*5=15 (1st part), 3*6=18 (2nd part), and Peter Phipps' answer (3rd part) is very nice. Exactly for puzzle solving.

Answer (score 1):

ANS-366329

-36(multiplication of first two digits(9*4))
-63-(multiplication of end digits(9*7))
-29(add 36+63 and minus the last digit(7) ansd reverse the it i.e. 36+63-7=92 reverse of 92 is 29

Comment: This doesn't answer the question , but well , thanks for the try, I already know the answer :) .